# Magento store and display ajax cookie in front end

Tags: magento-1.9, cookie

when user comes first time in a site it will ask for category subcategory etc..after that i store all value into session then if user come to home page it will show it's working fine for all except subcategory

```
  <?php $tree = $this->helper('techinflo_shop')->getCategoriesDropdown(); ?>
 <?php 
      $categoryvalue = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getCategoryValue();
      $attributeValue = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getAttributeValue();
      $homecityvalue = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getHomeCityValue();
      $subcategoryvalue = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getSubCategoryValue();
    ?> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    var children = $H(<?php echo json_encode($tree['children']) ?>);
    function showCat(obj, level) {
        hideContent();
        var catId = obj.value;
        level += 1;
        if ($('cat_container_' + level)) {
            $('cat_container_' + level).remove();
        }
        if (children.get(catId)) {
            var options = children.get(catId);
            //var html = '<select class="form-control" name="subcategory" required="required" id="cat_' + catId + '" onchange="showCat(this, ' + level + ')">';
            var html = '<select class="form-control" name="subcategory" required="required" id="cat_' + catId + '" onchange="showCat()">';
            //html += '<option value=""disabled selected> Select </option>';

            html += '<option value="' + options[i].entity_id + '"' + (options[i].entity_id == '<?php echo $subcategoryvalue?>') ? ' selected="selected"' : '' + '>' + options[i].name + '</option>';  


            for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                html += '<option value="' + options[i].entity_id + '">' + options[i].name + '</option>';
            }
            html += '</select>';
            html = '<div id="cat_container_' + level + '">' + html + '</div>';

            $('sub_cat').insert(html);
        }
    }
    //window.onload=showContent();  
     /*function showContent(){
        document.getElementById("default-content").style.display="block";
    }
    function hideContent(){
        document.getElementById("default-content").style.display="none";
    }*/
    function onLoad()
{
    showContent();
    showCat(document.getElementById('first_cat'), 2);
}

window.onload=onLoad();
</script>

<form role="form" method="post" action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('location/index'); ?>" onsubmit="return validation();">
    <div class="search_content_area">
        <div class="i">
            <span> I am a </span>
        </div>
        <div class="category">
            <select id="first_cat" onchange="showCat(this, 2)" class="form-control" required="required" name="parentcate">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
                <?php foreach ($tree['first'] as $cat): ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $cat->getUrlKey() ?>" <?php echo ($categoryvalue==$cat->getId())?'selected':'' ?>><?php echo $cat->getName() ?></option>
                <?php endforeach ?>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="city">
            <span> Shopping City </span>
        </div>
        <div class="select-city">
            <select class="form-control" id="mytext1" required="required" name="homecity">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
                <option value="Bangalore" <?php echo ($homecityvalue=='Bangalore')?'selected':'' ?>>Bangalore</option>
                <option value="Calcutta" <?php echo ($homecityvalue=='Calcutta')?'selected':'' ?>>Calcutta</option>
                <option value="Chennai" <?php echo ($homecityvalue=='Chennai')?'selected':'' ?>>Chennai</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="look">
            <span> Looking For </span>
        </div>
        <div id="sub_cat"></div>
        <div id="default-content">
        <div id="cat_container_va">
          <select class="form-control" id="mytext">
            <option disabled selected>Select</option>
          </select> 
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="by">
            <span> By </span>
        </div>
        <div class="brand">          
            <select class="attribute-brand form-control" id="attribute" required="required" name="attribute"> 
                  <option>Select</option>
                <?php 
                $attributes = Mage::getModel('catalogsearch/advanced')->getAttributes();
                $attributeArray=array();
                foreach($attributes as $a){
                  if($a->getAttributeCode() == 'brand'){
                    foreach($a->getSource()->getAllOptions(false) as $option){?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $option['value'];?>" <?php echo ($attributeValue==$option['value'])?'selected':'' ?>><?php echo $option['label'];?></option>
                    <?php }
                  }
                }

                ?>
            </select> 
          </div>
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-block let-shop" type="submit">Go</button>
    </div>


    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that when you build the subcategory you do not set a selected value.

```
html += '<option value="' + options[i].entity_id + '">' + options[i].name + '</option>';
```

Try changing it to this:

```
html += '<option value="' + options[i].entity_id + '"' + (options[i].entity_id == '<?php echo $subcategoryvalue?>') ? ' selected="selected"' : '' + '>' + options[i].name + '</option>';
```

I haven't tested the code, so be careful at possible syntax error.

[EDIT]

I see that the subcategories dropdown appears after you call the function `showCat` on changing the category dropdown.
When the page loads this does not happen.
So you can try to add this code inside your script tag:

```
function onLoad()
{
    showContent();
    showCat(document.getElementById('first_cat'), 2);
}
```

And replace the line `window.onload=showContent();` with `window.onload=onLoad();`

Comment: After change sub category dropdown also not showing

Comment: ahh..it is not showing. I thought it is showing but not selecting the correct value

Comment: No luck check my updated question of full code

Comment: You commented the code for `showContent`. Put it back. same for `hideContent`

Comment: Sorry i am not getting i need to uncoment hidecontent or what

Comment: No luck can you please update full code i got confuse

Comment: you commented 2 functions in js. Remove the comments for this: `/*function showContent(){
        document.getElementById("default-content").style.display="block";
    }
    function hideContent(){
        document.getElementById("default-content").style.display="none";
    }*/`

Comment: yes afetr that if i change main category subcategory hided

Comment: That's all I could do. Sorry, I have no more ideas.